# Why Cant we access the `MilestoneStatus` field either on the `Workflow` or `Process Builder` or in `formula` field?

Tags: apex, workflow, casemilestone, entitlements

Why Cant we access the `MilestoneStatus` field either on the `Workflow` or `Process Builder` or in `formula` field ?

As per current implementation, my Case Detailed page is pure custom and I have `Entitlement Processes` and `Milestones` in place. The thing is that I cant access the **Milestone Status Icon** field, but I can access the `MilestoneStatus` value. That value I need to populate into `Custom Milestone Status Icon` and using formula field I wants to show the Milestone Status Icon.

How can I approach to this implementation ?

I got the reference here : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000171150&language=en_US&type=1

But how can I populate `custom picklist field` if I dont have access to Milestone Status field using Workflow, PB etc?

Note: I have almost 5 Milestones on each entitlement processes and almost 40 Entitlement Processes. I only need to used OOTB MilestoneStatus which gets calculate the value automatically that value I wants to populate to different field and formula field will just show the correct Icon.

Can we implement using `Queueable` interface?

Answer (score 2):

As it's explained in the [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000171150&language=en_US&type=1) Case.MileStonestatus is a very special field, populated and treated differently as most other fields in Salesforce. Schema reports the field as String(30).

Even if it is displayed in Setup, in my tests (Execute Anonymous Context) it seems not to be accessible by Apex

```
Case c = new Case();
c.Subject='test';
c.MilestoneStatus = 'test';
insert c;
```

> Variable does not exist: MilestoneStatus

Nor is it available in SOQL queries

```
[ select Id, MilestoneStatus from Case limit 1 ]
```

> No such column 'MilestoneStatus' on entity 'Case'. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after
>   the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
>   for the appropriate names.

**So implementing the `Queueable` interface is unlikely to work.**

The Knowledge Article recommends

> Workaround:
>
> Have a picklist field (e.g. Status or a custom picklist field) that
>   can be populated dynamically basing on the Milestone Status Value. 
>   After having the picklist field, create a formula field that will set
>   the value same as the Milestone Status basing on the Picklist value
>   that has been set.
>
> Example:   If your case status = abc and this is the criteria for
>   milestone a, then you code your formula field to return a value of
>   milestone a if the status = abc.

Now my interpretation of this is that you are encouraged to implement an independent formula field which is mimicking the result of MilestoneStatus. But like you I find this workaround worded not very clearly and hard to understand. Salesforce should have provided a real example with the actual code of the formula to avoid misunderstandings and guesswork.

Comment: I was already aware about this workaround mentioned over web. My only ask  "Have a picklist field (e.g. Status or a custom picklist field) that can be populated dynamically basing on the Milestone Status Value" - How we can actually do this ? Any code ? Any thought ? How practically its possible ?

Comment: As said above it looks almost impossible, while the interpretation of the Salesforce workaround is hard. What I understand is that you should rebuild (mimic, duplicate) the entire MilestoneStatus criteria in a formula. Hardly viable I guess.

Comment: You're right I guess, in my org I have almost 40 Entitlement Processes and 120 milestones, still I see impossible solution. I dont see any viable solution and seems salesforce limitations. I was not able to show to client what I had promissed.

Comment: Maybe replicating the entire mechanism by Workflow, ProcessBuilder or Apex Trigger could help - however it would require a deep overhaul of what you got so far. I can't figure a Formula can do it because of its limitations.

Comment: What else I can show is that only the Milestone Status and not the Milestone Status Icon.